# Can someone be confidential?

Tags: meaning

I understand what confidential information means, but can a person be confidential? Can you use it to describe a person who you can trust with sensitive information? "She is organized, resourceful and confidential?"

Comment: It's a common usage to say _"She is a very close friend. I can confide in her anything"_.

Comment: No, a person can't be "confidential." So a sentence like "Tim is confidential" is wrong. However a person could be a "confidential adviser" for instance.

Comment: Why not? I know someone who is [*a confidential secretary*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/confidential)!

Comment: Because a "*confidential person*" would be someone who other people are not supposed to know about, and and *not* a person who can keep confidences.

Comment: @Maulik in that case, *confidential* describes the duties of the position - what sort of information the secretary handles - not the person. It's saying *a secretary who handles secret information*, not *a secretary who can be trusted with secrets*.

Comment: There's also confidential informant for another term here  "The term is usually used within the law enforcement world, where they are officially known as confidential or criminal informants (CI), and can often refer pejoratively to the supply of information without the consent of the other parties with the intent of malicious, personal or financial gain." from Wikipedia

Comment: @JBKing But that too is a case where "confidential" really modifies the act of informing (or the act of performing secretarial duties) embedded within the noun "informant" (or "secretary").  Any adjective modifying a "doer" noun has this property Thus "illegal immigrant" triggers the "A person is not illegal!" objection raised by people who don't really understand how English works ("illegal" modifies the act of immigration, not the person doing it).

Comment: @Monty has nailed it. These cases are *compound* nouns, not *described* nouns.

Answer (score 17):

A person who can **keep a secret** (confidential information) is said to be

> a **confidant**
>   **discreet**
>   **tight-lipped**
>   **trusted**
>
> The woman was his mistress and **confidant**.
>   The manager **discreetly** handled the situation to not draw any attention.
>   The concierge was **tight-lipped** about the personal matters of the hotel guests.
>   Her **trusted** aide never revealed what happened behind the scenes.

Comment: Not to be confused with _"confident"_.

Comment: +1 for confidant, I think that's exactly the word OP is looking for.

Comment: @Mast except that confidant is a noun, and OP is looking for an adjective.

Comment: @corsiKa "She is organized, resourceful and a confidant" would work I think.

Comment: @corsiKa OP never stated looking for an adjective, only something "to describe a person who you can trust with sensitive information"

Comment: I'd be more careful with _a confidant_, as it implies that you [already confide](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/confidant) in her. _Discreet_ would be better choice if you are describing general trait

Answer (score 7):

No, generally the word used for that is "discreet". A discreet person is sensitive to secrets and won't misuse them. "Trustworthy" is also good in a more broad sense.

Answer (score 4):

I can think of one sense in which a person can be "confidential". It means somebody whose identity is confidential. The term "confidential informant" or "confidential source" can refer to someone who gives information to someone else under an agreement not to publish his or her name.

- One example is a ["whistleblower"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whistleblower), or someone who witnesses abuse within an organization and reports this abuse to the mass media.
- Another is a ["criminal informant"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Informant), a former criminal who cooperates with a police investigation in exchange for less harsh punishment.